# Define todo keyword in Python and Sublime Text

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, keyword, todo

Can I define **`#@TODO`** or something like that as a keyword to be highlighted in Python?

Is this specific to the text editor or to the language/platform?

Comment: Everything that has to do with highlighting is specific to the editor you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very specific to the editor.
Language/Platform has nothing to do with highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

it s editor feature, eclipse has highlighter, in emacs you can define and ...

also you can use bash script to find all todo in your project

```
grep "# TODO" ./ -Rn
```